# passing database array to flot

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a php file that returns a json-encoded array of arrays in this format:

```
[["2005","93"],["2006","98"],["2007","104"],["2008","120"],["2009","88"],["2010","104"],["2011","78"],["2012","96"],["2013","89"],["2014","100"],["2015","20"]]
```

I want to use this data in a flot graph, but nothing is happening. This is my jquery flot code (with flot-axislabels). #byYear is the div in my html where the graph goes:

```
$.post('php/get_peoplebyyear.php', 
     function(output){              
            $(function () {
                var options = {
                    xaxis: {
                        axisLabel: 'year',
                        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 20,
                        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial'
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        axisLabel: 'number',
                        axisLabelUseCanvas: true
                    }
                };
                console.log(output);
                $.plot($("#byYear"),
                        [output],
                      options
                );
            });
     });
```

No points appear on my graph when I use this code. This is probably a small, silly error on my part, but could something tell me what I've done incorrectly please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it - basically, flot didn't interpret the output of my database query as an array of arrays, even though if I copied and pasted the output of my database query into the flot code, the flot graph worked.

So what I did was create two arrays, data and coordinate. Then I json parsed the database output and fed the coordinates, one pair at a time into coordinate, then pushed each coordinate into data:

```
$.post('php/get_myprogram.php', 
                 function(output){
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( output );
                        var data = [];
                        var coordinate = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i< obj.length; i++) {

                            coordinate.push(obj[i][0]);
                            coordinate.push(obj[i][1]);
                            data.push(coordinate);
                            coordinate = [];
                        }

                            var options = {
                                xaxis: {
                                    axisLabel: 'year',
                                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 20,
                                    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial'
                                },
                                yaxis: {
                                    axisLabel: 'number',
                                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true
                                }
                            };


                            $.plot($("#byYear"),
                                    [data],
                                   options
                            );

                 });
```

Comment: That is strange, does it work if you only do the `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(output);` and then use `[obj]` instead of `[data]` in the `plot` call?

Answer (score 0):

The data is in the right format but your callback function is wrong. Remove the

```
$(function () {
```

at the start and one

```
});
```

at the end of your function.